# Run Method from second project

Tags: vb.net

I have two projects:

1. MakeCall.exe
2. Caller.exe

MakeCall will be opened with a terminal command from a extern application.

```
start MakeCall.exe 0172000444000
```

Because Caller.exe will always run and is even though a single instance application I need the MakeCall.exe to set up a call.

What I would like to do:
Run a method in Caller.exe from the MakeCall.exe to set up a call.

E.g. to access Flowfact with its method you just have to write

```
Dim API = GetObject("","FFDeveloper.Application")
```

PS: I am running Visual Studio 2015

Comment: have you looked at the [Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1):

In Caller.EXE...

```
Public Class Class1
  Public Sub CallSomeone(phone As String)
    MsgBox(phone)
  End Sub
End Class
```

In MakeCall.EXE...

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
  Sub InvokeCallerEXE()
    Dim strAssemblyName As String = "c:\Junk\Caller.exe"

    Dim asm As Assembly
    asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(strAssemblyName)
    Dim strTypeName As String = "Class1"
    Dim typCaller As System.Type = asm.GetType(strTypeName)
    Dim caller As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typCaller)
    caller.CallSomeone("12345")
  End Sub
End Module
```

NOTE: I think this just executes the method, it doesn't hook a running instance.

Comment: `Dim caller as Object = ...`

System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: Did you set the correct path for strAssemblyName? It needs to point to where Caller.exe lives. Also, Caller.exe needs to be a .NET executable.